# kotlin's javaclass.isPrimitive fails if parameter compile-time is not actual type

Tags: class, kotlin, primitive

The following code

```
fun foo(value:Double) {
    if(!value.javaClass.isPrimitive) {
        println("try again")
        return
    }
}
    println("that's nice")
}

fun main() {
    foo(0.0)
}
```

displays:
"that's nice"

but setting `value` type as `Any`:

```
fun foo(value:Any) {
        if(!value.javaClass.isPrimitive) {
            println("try again")
            return
        }
        println("that's nice")
    }

fun main() {
    foo(0.0)
}
```

will display: "try again"
even though `value`runtime type **is** `Double`,
link for testing : https://pl.kotl.in/HkghkAkF4

quote from https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.jvm/java-class.html:

> inline val  T.javaClass: Class
>
> Returns the runtime Java class of this object

which from https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isPrimitive should give me right

EDIT: removed unnecessary run{}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you declare the type as `Double`, that's a primitive `double` (rather than the `Double` wrapper class).

When you declare the type as `Any`, the method then accepts any *object* as a parameter, so even if you pass in a primitive `double`, it will be auto-boxed into a wrapper object for `Double` and will no longer be a primitive.

You can see this by running this snippet on [play.kotlinlang.org](https://play.kotlinlang.org):

```
fun main() {
    useDouble(3.0)
    useAny(3.0)
}

fun useDouble(value: Double) = println("${value.javaClass.name}")
fun useAny(value: Any) = println("${value.javaClass.name}")
```

Prints:

```
double
java.lang.Double
```

Comment: and how do i get my head around that? I need to analyze any kind of value

Comment: That's what you're doing by declaring the type as `Any`. A method can't accept both a primitive and an object, so to support it, the primitives must be auto-boxed into a wrapper object.

Comment: but I can only accept certain types of data : primitives, string and a certain class, I reject the others, isn't there a method like "isPrimitive" for wrapper classes?

Comment: If you can only accept certain types, why not declare methods explicitly for those supported types? That way you fail at compile-time if you pass in an unsupported value.

Answer (score 3):

> isn't there a method like "isPrimitive" for wrapper classes

Not directly, but you can check whether a value belongs to a wrapper class by

```
value::class.javaPrimitiveType != null
```

Or if you just have a `clazz: Class<T>`,

```
clazz.kotlin.javaPrimitiveType != null
```